# Detecting when new file is added in a folder

Tags: android

In my app I have to detect when a new file is added in a folder, but I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400561/receiving-event-if-a-file-was-downloaded-added-to-download-folder) post that FileObserver can not be used for newest Android versions (>6.0) so I'm asking: how can I do it? With ContentObserver? If yes, is there any example from where I can see how to use it?

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more? There might be a better solution for your problem. Why do you need to observe a file?

Comment: I need to show a notification when a new file is added in a determinated folder (for example, if I set the observing folder to download folder and I download a file, it will notify me about the presence of a new file in download folder)

Answer (score 0):

Android can terminate any process by time, user choice and/or free up RAM; therefore, something like FileObserver is unreliable.

You need three parts:

A Service were the magic goes.
The activity (foreground app) which will launch the service (if not already active)

An activity: to launch the service

A BroadcastReceiver which will receive a signal when the service is killed so it can restart it.

```
public class CheckFolderServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, CheckFolderService.class));
    }
}
```